# Data-id attribute not showing up when added to display:none element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm building out a notification popup with bootstrap popover. The popover has a div for each notification, each with the same classes (identical except text content).

```html
<% notifs.each do |notif| %>
  <div class="media n-media notif-popup-container notif-display" data-id=<%= notif.id %> >
    Content
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Which results in this:

[notif-popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmGtR.png)

However, when I click on any of the notification divs (in the picture), my click listener's $(this) will always refer to the first div. I know this because when I print the ID, it will print the first notification div's ID even when the third is clicked.

Couldn't find a similar question elsewhere. Here's the relevant jquery code. I'm using $(body).on("click") instead of $(".className").click because the latter will not attach to the desired div since the div has display:none until it pops up.

```js
$('body').on("click", ".popover-body .notif-popup-container", function() {
    console.log("notif popup container clicked");

    // prints <div class="media n-media notif-popup-container notif-display"></div> 
    console.log($(this)[0]);

    // prints {}
    console.log($(this).data());

    // prints first element's id
    console.log($('.notif-popup-container').data("id"));

    // prints undefined
    console.log($(this).data("id"));
 })
```

Here's the popover code. I noticed that the data-id attribute wasn't showing in chrome dev tools only for my style="display:none" divs. These divs get inserted into the options for popover title and content, so they have to be hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#notificationsBell").popover({
    'title' : $('.notifications-title-header').html(), // display:none for html div
    'html' : true,
    'placement' : 'left',
    'content' : $(".notifications-list").html() // display:none for this as well
  });
});
```

The JS might give some hints. Building with Rails, but that seems irrelevant. Any insight appreciated.

Edit: It wasn't getting the first div, it was getting the correct one. It just wasn't keeping the data-id attribute. So now I will be storing it in the "id" attribute, which will show on chrome dev tools. I would still like to know why data-id doesn't show up, and id attribute does.

Edit 2: Here is the relevant html code:

```html
  <%= link_to "javascript:void(0);", class: "dropdown-toggle", id: "notificationsBell" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-bell dropdown-toggle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span id="notifUnreadCount">
      <%= Notification.unread_count(current_user) %>
    </span>
  <% end %>

  <div style="display:none" class="notifications-title-header" data-id="sup">
    <p class="notifications-title">
      Notifications
      <span class="see-all-notifs"><u><%= link_to "See all", notifications_path %></u></span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none" class="notifications-list">

    <% unread_notifications = Notification.unread_count(current_user) %>
    <% if unread_notifications === 0 %>

      No notifications to display! You are up to date.

    <% else %>
      <% notifs = current_user.notifications.where(read_at: nil).order("created_at DESC") %>
      <% notifs.each do |notif| %>

        <div class="media n-media notif-popup-container notif-display" id=<%= notif.id %> >

          <%= image_tag "bell.svg", class: "notification-icon-small mr-3" %>

          <div class="media-body noti-info">
            <b><p><%= notif.notify_type %></p></b>
            <span class="n-date trans-timestamp dateTime" data-momentiz="(<%= notif.momentize %>)"></span>
            <p><%= notif.message %></p>
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
            <% if notif.status == 'pending' && notif.target.present? %>
              <%= link_to update_request_wager_path(notif.target.try(:wager), member_id: notif.target_id, type: "accept", notif_id: notif.id), method: :put, class: "btn table-link acceptBtn red-btn-small", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to accept?' } do %>
                <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <% end %>
              <%= link_to update_request_wager_path(notif.target.wager, member_id: notif.target_id, type: "reject", notif_id: notif.id), method: :put,class: "btn table-link rejectBtn red-btn-small", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to reject?' } do %>
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to get_notification_url(notif) + "#" + notif.notify_type.downcase + "Notif", class: "btn red-btn-small" do %>
                <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% end %>
          </div>


        </div>


      <% end %>

    <% end %>

  </div>
```

Comment: your code seems to work as expected, can you provide the html built by rails ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that your generated HTML will be like the following... All divs contain the same multiple class as "media n-media notif-popup-container notif-display". On click event have to use any one of the classes as ".notif-popup-container" or ".notif-display" and this code will be work properly.

```
   <div class="media n-media notif-popup-container notif-display" data-id="1">
        Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="media n-media notif-popup-container notif-display" data-id="2">
        Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="media n-media notif-popup-container notif-display" data-id="3">
        Content 3
    </div>
```

The sample code snippets as

```
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $('body').on("click", ".notif-popup-container", function () {
               console.log($(this).data("id"));
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Or it can be like this...

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('body').on("click", ".notif-display", function () {
            console.log($(this).data("id"));
        });
     });
    </script>
```

I hope that this will be work fine... cheer

Comment: Hi Azizur, actually the divs look almost exactly like you said, except the data-id attribute is not showing up in the chrome dev tools. And weirdly enough, when I change the display:none to display:show, the data-id attribute will be visible as part of the div. It also shows up on any other div element on the page that is not hidden (found from testing it out). Maybe that will provide some clues? The reason I have display:none on the overall div is because provide it to the popover title and content options when initializing the popover. See edit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### [Event Delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Event delegation is a programming pattern which allows us to listen for events for multiple (unlimited amount) target tags (ex. `buttons`, `inputs`, etc.) by binding (aka register) event(s) to a single tag that all target tags have in common as an ancestor. I refer to it as the "common ancestor" -- `window`, `document`, and `body` are always valid, but not the best choice in most cases.

Besides having only one event handler in the call stack, any target tag dynamically added to the page after it has loaded will react to registered triggered events -- there is no way to bind events to tags created post page load.

jQuery [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method delegates events when the actual selector is provided:

```
$('.btn-group').on('click',...
```

`.btn-group` is the tag (common ancestor) bound to event(s) and will listen for those events when triggered on any of its descendant tags (target tags). There are many ways to reference `.btn-group` within the handler:

**`$('.btn-group')`**

```
this                   // Used with plain JavaScript properties and methods
$(this)[0]             // As above
$(this).get()          // As above
event.currentTarget    // As above*
$(this)                // Used with jQuery properties and methods
$(event.currentTarget) // As above*
```

*[`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) will always reference the tag bound to event, but that's not always true for `this`. If the second parameter called [`event.data`](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/) is defined as a selector, then `this` will reference `event.data`.

```
$('.btn-group').on('click', '.btn-modal', openModal);
```

`$(.btn-modal)` is also `$(this)` now, not `$('.btn-group')`. Any descendant tag of `$('.btn-group')` that is clicked triggers the click event thereby calling the handler function `openModal()`. It is the handler that will determine what tag initiates behavior or is ignored. The tags that are triggers when clicked can be referenced by the following:

**Event Origin** - The tag the user clicked, changed, hovered over, etc.

```
event.target    // Used with plain JavaScript properties and methods
this            // As above if `event.data` is defined
$(this)[0]      // As above
$(this).get()   // As above
$(event.target) // Used with jQuery properties and methods
$(this)         // As above if `event.data` is defined
```

[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will always reference the tag that the user has interacted with (ex. clicked).

---

#### Demo

**Note:** Details commented in demo

```js
/*
If there are multiple tags to target

  ex. 3 button.btn-modal
  
Determine the closest parent tag that the target tags have in common. 

  ex. fieldset.btn-group
  
Delegate the event to the "common ancestor". Add the handler function 
(ie `openModal()`) without the parenthesis.

  ex. $('.btn-group').on('click', openModal);
  
*/
$('.btn-group').on('click', openModal);

/*
Pass thru the event object
Use the event object property .target to determine which tag the user clicked. 
Make it into a jQuery object by wrapping it into $(...)

  ex. let clicked = $(event.target);
  
If the clicked tag has a .btn-modal class...

  ex. if (clicked.hasClass('btn-modal')) {...
  
...get the clicked tag data-open value...

  ex. let ID = clicked.data('open');
  
...Finally, use previous value, ID, as a reference to a modal using the Bootstrap 
method .modal() to open said modal.*

  ex. $('#'+ID).modal();
  
*/
function openModal(event) {
  let clicked = $(event.target);
  if (clicked.hasClass('btn-modal')) {
    let ID = clicked.data('open');
    $('#' + ID).modal();
  }
  return false;
}

/*
*Note: Patterns involving .btn-modal classes and data-open attributes 
are of my own design
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <section class='row'>

      <fieldset class='btn-group btn-group-lg mx-auto mt-5'>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-modal" data-open="noticeA" type="button">
          Notice A
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-modal" data-open="noticeB" type="button">
          Notice B
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-modal" data-open="noticeC" type="button">
          Notice C
        </button>
      </fieldset>

      <dialog id="noticeA" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <header class="modal-header bg-primary">
              <h4 class="modal-title text-white">Notice A</h4>
              <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
            </header>
            <article class="modal-body">
              <p class='display-1 text-center'>HEY!</p>
            </article>
            <footer class="modal-footer">
     <button class="close btn btn-primary p-3" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
       Close
     </button>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </dialog>

      <dialog id="noticeB" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <header class="modal-header bg-warning">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Notice B</h4>
              <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
            </header>
            <article class="modal-body">
              <p class='display-1 text-center'>HEY!</p>
            </article>
            <footer class="modal-footer">
     <button class="close btn btn-warning p-3" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
       Close
     </button>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </dialog>

      <dialog id="noticeC" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lx">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <header class="modal-header bg-danger">
              <h4 class="modal-title text-white">Notice C</h4>
              <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
            </header>
            <article class="modal-body">
              <p class='display-1 text-center'>HEY!</p>
            </article>
            <footer class="modal-footer">
     <button class="close btn btn-danger p-3" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">
       Close
     </button>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </dialog>

    </section>
  </main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0
/umd/popper.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi zer00ne, your answer was very informative but in my special case there are some different details important to bridge the gap. 1. The common ancestor of my .notif-popup-container element that is visible on the DOM on page load is actually "body", so that is the only one that will work in terms of delegation. 2. event.target is a bit too specific, it might get the specific <p></p> of the actual desired .notif-popup-container div depending on where the user clicks inside that div. 3. The data-id attribute still does not show up. It may have something to do with :hidden property, look @ edits!

Comment: Hi @KevinSun If you want a definitive answer then post the HTML. Concerning point 2. `event.target` is what you need exactly. When you delegate the event the handler must be written with conditionals (ex. `if/else if/else`, `switch()`, ternary expression, etc). If done correctly, only the tags you want will react to the registered event. The event attachment to the `body` has a handler designed for testing...but it is useless because it gives out a false positive. I cannot go into full details because I still need the HTML to assess the issues with certainty.

Comment: Hi @zer00ne, I've posted the html. I've gotten around the data-id attribute not showing up on the element by just using the "id" attribute, which does show up. But I am still curious as to why the data-id doesn't show up! Thanks.